# Texlive 2019 offline installation from iso image on Linux

Tags: installing, linux, texlive-2019

I have put a downloaded iso image of Texlive 2019 on Linux (Mint 19.3, 32 bit) desktop.
I open the terminal in the desktop and perform the following commands

```
$ mkdir mountpoint
$ sudo mount -o loop texlive2019-20190410.iso mountpoint
$ Password:
$ cd mountpoint/
$ ./install-tl
```

Everything works and the following prompt appears

```
Actions:
 <I> start installation to hard disk
 <P> save installation profile to 'texlive.profile' and exit
 <H> help
 <Q> quit
```

I press I, but I get the following error:

```
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2019

install-tl: No binary platform specified/available, quitting.
```

How can one solve this problem?

P.S. I can install Texlive without problem on Windows with the same iso image.

Comment: What does `$ ./install-tl -print-platform` say?

Comment: Sorry, it says `i386-linux`.

Comment: Then try `$ ./install-tl -force-platform i386-linux`

Comment: With `./install-tl -force-platform i386-linux` I get the same error as in the body of my question.

Comment: Have you tried `$ sudo ./install-tl`?

Comment: Yes, with `sudo` the same error appears. I came across https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496513/how-to-install-texlive-from-dvd-onto-a-32bit-linux-machine

Comment: Mystery solved!