# How to install texlive 2020 from the DVD on a Linux box?

Tags: installing, texlive-2020

For many years I have installed texlive from the DVD onto my Linux 32 bit box. This failed with the 2020 release. In 2017 there were 19 systems supported. In 2020 the manual listed support for 16 systems. I use(d) the **GNU/Linux on Intel (i386-linux)**. When installing from the 2020 DVD only about 6 systems were listed, practically all for 64 bit machines, in contrast with the manual. The i386-linux was not among 6 systems. I tried the 64 bit offering but the resulting binaries were inoperable.

How can I install the 2020 texlive distribution? Fortunately the 2019 texlive still works.

I suppose a bodge would be to try and use the 2019 binaries instead of the failed 2020 ones by altering the PATH but would the 2020 packages be picked up?

Comment: The manual is about TeX Live, not specifically the DVD; is a DVD-base install vital?

Comment: They cannot got everything onto the dvd anymore. Any reason you don't just use the online installer it provides all architectures

Comment: same scenario as in this post? see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496513/how-to-install-texlive-from-dvd-onto-a-32bit-linux-machine
does this manual help: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable ?

Comment: See also the answer I gave to the post in naphaneals comment.

Comment: @JosephWright I think that the manual should be changed along the lines of saying that X systems (list them) are supported in general but only Y systems (list them) are provided on the DVD; if you need non-DVD systems then use the Net installer. I have spent a lot of time following the manual when it turns out to be unclear.

Comment: @daleif It seems that I installed the 2019 version via the online installer. I am trying it for the 2020 version but it is taking over twice as long from the DVD. The manual should make clear what is, and is not, available via the DVD. To me it is far more convenient to slip in a DVD and run it rather than download lots of stuff from the internet. TUG could save money by not sending the DVD to those people who use unsupported systems. (My 32 bit system does all that I need so I see no point in spending money getting a 64 bit system).

Comment: I haven't used the DVD in 10+ years, and I still get the DVD from TUG. It does say on `http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-dvd.html` that less commonly used binaries are not on the DVD, and it links to http://tug.org/texlive/doc.html#platforms where the platforms not on the DVD are listed.

Comment: @daleif The internet install eventually finished and after a few minor tests texlive 2020 seems to be working.

Comment: Online install can take a very long time if one have an aggressive anti virus (we have on our windows pcs) or have a slow Internet connection. In the latter can installing a smaller scheme can be a good choice then install missing packages over time via tlmgr

Comment: @naphaneal Thank you. I dod not remember asking the question a year ago. Getting older the more you forget.